# User prefix, code not working in discord.py rewrite branch

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Figured it out, i was just missing an return statement

```
def get_prefix(bot, message):
   if message.author.id == 1:
      return ["user prefix"]
   else:
      return ["default prefix"]
```

Comment: Can you add a bit more of your code? This one line can't be everything.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell in your post, you are trying to make a customizable prefix that can be unique to each server? This isn't the only way to do this, but in my bot, I use a json file to add and store all the users prefixes. This is a pretty basic way to do this but it works for my bot the way it is; given it does take a tiny bit understanding of how json files work. Here is a bit of code which does what I think you are looking for:

```
import json # put this wherever you put your other imports

def get_prefix(client, message): # have this below your on_ready event
    if not message.guild:
        return "your prefix"

    try:
        with open("./prefixes.json", "r") as f: # prefixes is just an example filename. You can use whatever you want for your json prefixes filename
            prefixes = json.load(f)

        return prefixes[str(message.guild.id)]

    except nextcord.DiscordException: # i'm using nextcord, a discord.py fork but it should be essentially the same with dpy
        return "your prefix"
```

The code above grabs the prefix for that guild/ server as identified in your json file, but you will also need a command that allows certain users to change the bot's prefix. That would probably go like this:

```
    @client.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(administrator=True) # or whatever permissions you want to require the user changing the prefix to have
    async def prefix(ctx, prefix):
        with open('./prefixes.json', 'r') as f: # same file as the one from before
            prefixes = json.load(f)
        
        prefixes[str(ctx.guild.id)] = prefix
        try:
            with open('./prefixes.json', 'w') as f:
                json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4) # changing the actual prefix from default to new prefix as specified in command
            embed = nextcord.Embed(description=f'Prefix successfully changed to {prefix}') # this is an example message I use just to say to the user that the prefix has been successfully changed
            await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed) # sends the embed you just created
        except nextcord.DiscordException: # general exception for discord, will change for you using discord.py but it should only be a small change
            return
```

Additionally, you will need to either create or add to your on_guild_remove and on_guild_join to on remove, get rid of the row in your json file with the guild id and it's specific prefix, and on join, create a new row with the guild id and it's default prefix. That would look something like this:

```
    @client.event() # if in cog it would be a listener instead
    async def on_guild_join(self, guild):

        with open("./prefixes.json", "r") as f:
            prefixes = json.load(f)

        prefixes[str(guild.id)] = "your prefix"

        with open("./prefixes.json", "w") as f:
            json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)
# this event here would create something that looks like this inside your json file when your bot joins a new server: { "random guild id number": "your prefix" } 

    @client.event() # listener if in cog
    async def on_guild_remove(guild):
      
        with open("./prefixes.json", "r") as f:
            prefixes = json.load(f)

        prefixes.pop(str(guild.id))

        with open("./prefixes.json", "w") as f:
            json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)
          
        # loads your json file where the prefixes are stored and removes the row which stores the no longer joined guild
```

If you have any problems with the concepts or the code, just add a comment and i'll get back to you as soon as I can. This code should work but I am writing all of this somewhat quickly so please feel free to correct any of my mistakes. Hope this answers your question!

Comment: I know how to do that for guild, but I'm looking for per-user prefixes, for example, when i use commands my prefix would be "!", And that's only mine.

Comment: I don't know if that is possible but if it is, I would guess you could probably just replace some of the 'guild' attributes with user related code. Like instead of adding the guild id to the json file and pulling from that, add the user id and pull from that. Not 100% sure though this is the first time i've personally seen this type of concept

Comment: I'll try, I've seen quite some amount of people do this

Comment: Can you add some of your code to the question? If I can see your attempt at this feature maybe I can help better with what you are looking for

Comment: Got the correct code, scroll down for it

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_prefix(bot, message):
    m = message.author
    if m.id == 0000000:
        return ["your prefix here"]
    else:
        return ["default prefix here"]
```

Setting up

```
... = commands.Bot(command_prefix=get_prefix, ...)
```

Note that you don't need to call the function